# Product custom options in cart page magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I have to add product custom options in cart page. Is that possible . kindly help me anyone. I tried

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml")->toHtml();

include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml'));
```

not working. please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can show the block path in

```
system -> configuration -> change Current Configuration Scope into your default store view -> scroll to bottom
```

and click
`developer -> debug -> change Template Path Hints value to "yes"` Then Hit save.

Reload your cart page and now you can view your block path to add your custom option.

to hide the path, change your Template Path Hints value to "no".

Comment: I was check but not working . please give me solution humairoh

Comment: add your custom option code on your block path.

Comment: $block->getChildHtml('product.info.options'); is that right? please send custom option path, am new to magento